# pandas.read_sql processing speed

Tags: python, pandas

I need for further processing the result set of a MySQL query as a dataframe. The SQL table contains about 2 million rows and 12 columns (Data size = 180 MiB).
I'm running OS X 10.9 with 8 GB memory. Is it normal that [pandas.read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html) takes more than 20 secs to return the dataframe? How to implement a chunk size option like in [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)?

**Edit:**
Python 2.7.6,
pandas 0.13.1

Comment: you can implement chunk sizes with a `LIMIT` statement in your query.

Comment: A (non-free) solution is to use [IOPro](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/iopro/)... atm SQL reading is slow as it uses temporary python objects while reading (rather than directly to numpy).

Comment: IOPro seems to be what I need. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Starting from 0.15, `to_sql` has a `chunksize` option (0.15 is still in development, but the feature is merged in master)

Comment: BTW, using `chunksize` will not really make it faster, but it can prevent from running into packet size limitations or timing out of the connection.

Comment: @AndyHayden, Have they done anything to speed up SQL read..... Its a turtle, and takes a boatload of memory to load in "larger" size data. 90MB takes ridiculous 1GB to load into ipython.

Comment: @Merlin honestly i usually SQL -> csv -> pandas. that said there are efforts to slurp from sql in chunks (rather than row-by-row), there's definitely a GH issue... (the inverse of [this one](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8953) ) can't find it atm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#performance-considerations) shows that `read_sql()`/`read_sql_query()` takes about 10 times the time to read a file compare to `read_hdf()` and 3 times the time of `read_csv()`.

The `read_sql()` has now a chunk-size argument ( see the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html))

Comment: as joris mentioned above in comments , yes it doesnt help in execution . here he need to reduce the execution time